# unable to rewrite url through .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, urlrewriter

I want the url:

> www.tricore.in/viewdoc.php?did=2&title=mca-sem-2-syllabus

to rewrite like:

> http://tricore.in/docs/2/mca-sem-2-syllabus

But whenever I am clicking on any Link from *www.tricore.in*, the rewriting is not happening.

Below is the code of `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^browse/docs/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) docs.php?sortby=$1&filter=$2&page=$3&title=$4
   RewriteRule ^browse/categories/doc/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) categorydocs.php?sortby=$1&filter=$2&page=$3&title=$4
   RewriteRule ^browse/categories/docs/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) categorydocs.php?sortby=$1&filter=$2&page=$3&title=$4
   RewriteRule ^docs/(.*)/(.*) viewdoc.php?did=$1&title=$2
   RewriteRule ^confirmemail/(.*) confirmemail.php?code=$1
   RewriteRule ^download/doc/(.*)/(.*) downloaddoc.php?DID=$1&title=$2
   RewriteRule ^browse/members/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) members.php?sortby=$1&filter=$2&page=$3&title=$4
   RewriteRule ^categories/ categories.php
   RewriteRule ^members/profile/(.*)/(.*) memberprofile.php?pid=$1&username=$2
   RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) search.php?searchfor=$1&sortby=$2&page=$3&searchterm=$4
   RewriteRule ^syndicate/docs/(.*)/(.*) syndicatedocs.php?filter=$1&title=$2
   RewriteRule ^resetpassword/(.*) resetpassword.php?code=$1
   RewriteRule ^resendconfirmation/(.*) resendconfirmation.php?userid=$1
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c> 
   # Turn off mod_security filtering. 
   SecFilterEngine Off 

   # The below probably isn't needed, 
   # but better safe than sorry. 
   SecFilterScanPOST Off 
</IfModule>
```

Please tell me, where am I going wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: You do reverse oreration here `RewriteRule ^docs/(.*)/(.*) viewdoc.php?did=$1&title=$2` - it is from your .htaccess . So, what you want?

Comment: does any redirect works?

Comment: no redirects are working..same is with Member Page of the website when i click on any member its should show me the member details like http://tricore.in/memberprofile.php?pid=1 in redirected manner

Comment: even if i delete that perticular line from .htaccess file still it works, i mean no error 404 page cannot be found.

Comment: remove all Rules and add 
      `RewriteEngine on
      RewriteBase /
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*lala.php,*$
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /lala.php [L,R]` If you not see lala on any ask, your mod_rewrite.c seems doesn't work

Comment: hi, its throwing 500 Internal Server Error if i remove everything from .htaccess file and put the code you said above

Answer (score 2):

Please use the below rewrite rule. For this specific part.

```
RewriteRule ^docs/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /viewdoc.php?did=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Hi, Sachin..its not working..its the same..even if i delete that perticular line  .htaccess file this url rewrite still works but the only issue i said, it doesnt shows the pdf file when clicking on any thumbnail (i have very little knowledge of this but i feel it is not able to retrive viewdoc.php? file.

Comment: Rizwan, the above was a fix for your htaccess. Are you using the same exact rule I gave above ? It is clearly passing 'did' and 'title' to viewdoc.php.

Comment: Yes Sachin, I use exact same line, i tried deleting the entire line and then trying to access the link which redirects like Documents page, still i see the rwritten url but page is not called. same issue.

Comment: or stleast tell me how do i stop url_rewriting at all. coz now if i am deleting .htaccess file its throwing 404 error. Is there any way to stop rewriting.

Comment: Rizwan, you managed to get this URL work ( http://tricore.in/docs/2/mca-sem-2-syllabus ) ? And is the error occurring only when you click on links ?

Comment: yes Sachin, error occures only when i click on links who rewrite is writtent in .htaccess file like **Documents, Members** etc. but i dont get get error when i click on **Categories** its rewrite is simple
    RewriteRule ^categories/ categories.php

Comment: Sachin, I think url_rwrite rules is written in php for the link mentioned above. here is the entire script http://tricore.in/php_script.zip  please help me find the code where url is rewritten. thanks. sorry to bother u so much, i am basically .NET programmer

Comment: it is fixed now,
the Issue was, use **docs** in the rewrite    RewriteRule ^docs/(.*)/(.*) viewdoc.php?did=$1&title=$2

so now writing anything but docs are working.

Comment: Wow. Happy to know that. I hope my answer also helped you to get you there :-) Happy for you Rizwan.